# only this element not others that have the same class

Tags: jquery

I want to know is there any way in jQuery to point only to an element that for example is the child of parent of clicked btn. That has the same class that other elements have.

first Paragrapph

color

Second Paragraph

color

//jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btn').on("click",function(){
  $(this).parents().find('p').css('color','red');
  })
});
```

I want when btn is clicked only the paragraph `<p>` that is the child of parent of this clicked btn to get the CSS property.
I mean that point only to this object.

Comment: In this specific scenario, you could use the `prev`ious sibling: `$(this).prev('p').css('color','red');` But perhaps you are looking for a more generic answer?

Comment: You're almost there. Just swap parents() for parent(). You don't need to search all ancestors of this element.

Comment: I know that can use parent() instead of parents(), but in more complicated situation that for example that i want to find the ancestors. i should use it.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for more generic.

Comment: you should use `parent("div") `

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `parents` use parent as `<p>` is the parent of the button.

Here is the sample [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/seat4Lm6/)

Hope this Helps.

-Help :)

Comment: tnx. but I want to know that Jquery has this ability to point to the object that we want  to point  with 'this' or other pointer?

Answer (score 0):

use   [`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/)
 and `find` inner `Html`  control. Here i used `parent('div')` to find only ancestors.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btn').on("click",function(){
  $(this).parent('div').find('p').css('color','red');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <p>First Paragrapph</p>
   <button class="btn">color</button>
 </div>
 <div >
  <p>Second Paragraph</p>
  <button class="btn">color</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, it works

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btn').on("click",function(){
  $(this).siblings('p').css('color','red');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <p>First Paragrapph</p>
   <button class="btn">color</button>
 </div>
 <div >
  <p>Second Paragraph</p>
  <button class="btn">color</button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btn').on("click",function(){
  $(this).parent().find('p').css('color','red');
  })
});
```

Comment: While this can answer the question, it's better to provide some explanations about how this code help.

Answer (score 0):

my mistake is here.  body is one of ancestor of btn object. so it acts css on both

so i added a filter as my parents('filter'). and my problem solved.